# CMake arguments in a command invocation can end in a line comment

Tags: cmake

In the latest CMake documentation (may 2019), the *language* section, [*Source Files* paragraph](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#source-files) there is the following sentence:

> Note that any source file line not inside Command Arguments or a Bracket Comment can end in a Line Comment.

I think that source file lines inside *Command Arguments* can end in a *Line Comment* because the grammar specified in the [*Command Invocations* paragraph](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#command-invocations) states that a *line_ending* (which may contain a *line_comment*) can separate arguments.

Also, the following code snippet works as expected in cmake 3.11.4:

```
foreach(arg arg1
            arg2 #line-comment
       )
  message("${arg}")
endforeach()
```

Am I misunderstanding the above quote or is it inaccurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Command argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#command-arguments) is a specification of the **single** argument, which could be of one of three type:

> argument ::=  bracket_argument | quoted_argument | unquoted_argument

And you actually cannot specify a comment **inside** a command argument specification.

What you show in the question post, is a comment **after** the command argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that because the quote says: "[...] source file line not inside Command Arguments [...]", by *Command Arguments* it must mean the "section" that contains all the arguments (as the quote implies that the referred *Command Arguments* can span multiple lines). However, a *bracketed* or a *quoted* argument can span several lines. So the quote actually says that you cannot have a line that belongs to a *bracketed* or a *quoted* argument that ends in a *line comment*?

Comment: "You cannot have a line that belongs to a bracketed or a quoted argument that ends in a line comment?" - Yes, this is the actual meaning of the phrase.